# How to get the content from a System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, razor

I want to read the contents from a text file POSTed on a webpage from an `input type=file` on a form.
I do NOT want to save the file, only read it's content.

So far, after `if (IsPost)`...
`var uploadedFile = Request.Files[i];` I can get `uploadedFile.GetType()`, `uploadedFile.ContentLength` and `uploadedFile.FileName`, but how do I get the contents of the file, so I can write it on the webpage?

uploadedFile is a type System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper